# Приложение на Xamarin forms (android) не подключается к базе данных Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin.android, connection

Столкнулся с проблемой: приложение на Xamarin form не работает с локальной базой данных.
Брандмаузер выключен, в Sql Server включены все службы (проверено на моем готовом приложении на windows form).

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Запись_к_врачу_12;
 
 
namespace Запись_к_врачу_12
{
 
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public class zapisList
        {
            public int zapis_id { get; set; }
            public string Z_FIO { get; set; }
            public string Polis { get; set; }
            public string date_z { get; set; }
        }
 
        SqlConnection sqlConnection;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string srvrdbname = "site";
            string srvrname = "127.0.0.1";
            string srvrusername = "SH1F";
            string srvrpassword = "1379";
            string sqlconn = $"Data Source={srvrname};Initial Catalog={srvrdbname};User ID={srvrusername};Password={srvrpassword}";
            var conString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Database=site;" +
            "User ID=SH1F;Password=1379;Connect Timeout=30;" +
            "Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;" +
            "MultiSubnetFailover=False";
 
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conString);
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            button1.Clicked += Button1_Clicked;
        }
 
 
            private async void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.zapis VALUES(@zapis_id, @Z_FIO , @Polis ,@date_z)", sqlConnection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("zapis_id", id1.Text));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Z_FIO", fnl.Items[fnl.SelectedIndex]));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Polis", OMS.Text));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("date_z", date.Items[date.SelectedIndex]));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Уведомление", "ок", "ОК");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Ошибка", ex.Message, "ОК");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В программировании нет такого понятия: "не работает". Есть точное описание проблемы, с указанием исключения, текстом ошибки и прочими данными.

Comment: Для конструирования строки соединения из отдельных параметров используйте [Connection String Builders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders)

Comment: Мобильные приложения не предназначены для работы с БД. Прямой доступ к базе это архитектурная ошибка и дыра в безопасности, вам нужен серевер, который будет работать с базой, например ASP.NET Core WebAPI, он будет работать с базой, а приложение будет обращаться к серверу.

Comment: Попробовал connection string builder использовать ошибка та же (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server))

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй заменить свой conString а всё что выше закомментировать.
Работает если в SQL Server Managment Studio подключение через "Проверка подлинности SQL Server":

```
conString = "Server=(Имя сервера как при подключении SQL Managment);Database=(Название базы данных как в SQL);User Id=(Учётная запись в SQL);Password=(Пароль от учётной записи SQL);Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

В ином случае, если стоит "Проверка подлинности Windows":

```
conString = "Server=(Имя сервера как при подключении в SQL Server(Например: UserName\\SQLEXPRESS));Database=(Название базы данных(Например: test_01_02_03));Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

Данная проблема решается если проблема в подключении.
Если не понятно со скобками то:

```
conString = "Server=UserName\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test_01_02_03;User Id=sa;Password=123;Trusted_Connection=True;";
conString = "Server=UserName\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test_01_02_03;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

По хорошему бы тебе проверить подключение:

1. Создать текстовый файл (Название любое). Задать ему фармат .udl и запустить (Там ввести все данные и проверить подключение).
2. SQL Server Profiler - создаешь трассировку и подключаешься. Заходишь обратно в приложение (не закрывая Profiler) и пробуешь событие произвести, если в Profiler не реагирует, то проблема в подключении, что может тебе помочь выше перечисленное...